# Entity Framework Error String or binary data would be truncated in table

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am making a tweak to my table.

The scaffold is pretty straight forward, it's limiting the number of characters for some string columns.

I am presented with this error

> String or binary data would be truncated in table '', column 'DetailedDescription'. Truncated value: ''

I tried to do an update-database -force and it still won't let me

Migration Details

```
AddColumn("dbo.Tests", "AdditionalInstructions", c => c.String(maxLength: 2000));
AlterColumn("dbo.Tests", "DetailedDescription", c => c.String(maxLength: 500));
AlterColumn("dbo.Tests", "VenueName", c => c.String(maxLength: 100));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are applying a migration on an existing table that has some rows, the "String or binary data would be truncated in table" error means currently you have a stored string in the "DetailedDescription" column which its length is more than 500 characters. So, you should handle these values and try to run the `update-database` command again.